# c++ map find can't find specific Key

Tags: c++, dictionary, find

I'm using a map to store a bunch of keys and values. I want to use find() to find the key and return the value.  Unfortunately, when I can't find the key, it get's upset. How can I make it return 0 if no key is found?

```
 int bag::getItem( const string item)
 {
    return this->bagItems.find(item)->second;
    return 0;
 }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After a return call, the execution of this method stops, it does not make sense at all to use a return after another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`map::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) returns the value of `map::end()` if the value was not found. That's an iterator value that you cannot dereference, so blindly doing `bagItems.find(item)->second` is a no-no.

Instead, check the return value and act accordingly:

```
int bag::getItem( const string item) 
{ 
    // We don't know what CONST_ITERATOR_TYPE is, but you do
    CONST_ITERATOR_TYPE i = this->bagItems.find(item);
    return i == this->bagItems.end() ? 0 : i->second;
}
```

To do this, you 'll want to have a local variable of `const_iterator` type; however, that type depends on the template arguments of your map (which we don't know). So you will have to fill the blank in yourself.

If you are in the pleasant position of using a C++11 compiler, the convenient

```
auto i = this->bagItems.find(item);
```

will work.

Comment: isn't the Const_Iterator_Type = map?

Comment: @Lexicon: No, it's `map<K, V>::const_iterator`, where `K` and `V` are the same types you use to declare the `map` member.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That modifies the map by adding the key `item` with a default-constructed value if it did not already exist.

Answer (score 1):

you have to check the return value (it is an iterator) if it has found something:

```
int bag::getItem(const string & item) const
{
    map<string, int>::const_iterator iter = this->bagItems.find(item);
    return iter != this->bagItems.end() ? iter->second: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a check in `getItem()` method to see if the call to `find()` returned a bagItems.end(). If it did, you know the item was not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
int bag::getItem( const string item)
{

map::const_iterator iter =  this->bagItems.find(item); //correct type here ;]
if(iter != this.bagItems.end())
    return iter->second;

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the iterator is not at the end of the container

```
int bag::getItem( const string item)
 {
  {the type of bagItems}::const_iterator it ;
  it = bagItems.find(item) ;
  if ( it == bagItems.end()) {
    return 0;
  } else  {
      return bagItems.find(item)->second;
  }

 }
```